# how to add a new weka classification algorithm to weka

Tags: weka

I want to use some classification algorithm by weka(like c4.5, ID3) but I dont know how to add them to weka! Are they available on weka? and if these algorithm are not available how can I add them? And I could not find  weka.classifiers.trees
package on google

Comment: please consider changing the title of your question, to match the question-body.

Answer (score 1):

Weka's implementation of C4.5 (and its precursor ID3) is called *J48*. J is for Java  (and 48 is for 1998, or it is just some increment, I don't know).

Choose Weka Explorer, "Classify", "Classifier", "Tree" , "J48"

Click "More" Button:

> NAME weka.classifiers.trees.J48
>
> SYNOPSIS Class for generating a pruned or unpruned C4.5 decision tree.
>   For more information, see
>
> Ross Quinlan (1993). C4.5: Programs for Machine Learning. Morgan
>   Kaufmann Publishers, San Mateo, CA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are available in weka,
As knb mentioned, we talk about J48 as if it’s synonymous with C4.5 and you dont need to download it.
In order to use ID3 classification algorithm you should download a package named "simpleEducationalLearningSchemes".
for the full process to:
[Weka 3.8 Package installation: What are the steps to add id3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888463/weka-3-8-package-installation-what-are-the-steps-to-add-id3)
(There's an answer there written by G5W)