# Weka 3.8 Package installation: What are the steps to add id3?

Tags: weka, id3

I want to add (ID3) in trees in Weka version 3.8  What are the steps I should take ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get Id3, you will need to install the [simpleEducationalLearningSchemes](http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/simpleEducationalLearningSchemes/index.html) package. Your screen shot shows the Explorer window, but to install a package, you should go back to the GUI Chooser and select the Package Manager under the Tools menu.

[image: GUI Chooser]

Once you have opened the Package Manager, scroll down to select the `simpleEducationalLearningSchemes` package and click "Install"

[image: Installation Menu]

Once the package is installed, Id3 should appear as an option under the `trees` group of classifiers.